# Is the comma correct in the sentence?

Tags: punctuation, commas

I would like you to help me to explain the usage of the comma before "was" in this famous quote from Grand Theft Auto: San Andreas. I've already looked through many grammar textbooks but haven't found the exact answer to my question.

> All we had to do, was follow the damn train, CJ!

In my estimation, there seems to be either just a common mistake or author's solution to emphasise this part of the sentence.

Comment: It's fine without a comma.

Comment: I know that the sentence will be correct without this comma but would like to know why the author decided to put it here.

Comment: "All we had to do" is a noun clause standing for the subject.  Not sure why comma was used by the author. He might possibly have felt the need for a demarcation there.

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't put the comma there by myself, but there was quite a long pause between these words in the scene, so I think the comma was for that. Anyway, thanks for you help.

Comment: Yes, there's a pull towards compartmentalisation of the twin ... in effect, _statements_ ... 'That was all we had to do!' and  'We had to follow the train!' But Sentence + sentence, or sentence + fragment ('That was all we had to do! ... Follow the train!') is the way to add dramatic emphasis. The commaed version is non-standard. Comma-less, as @Ram says, fine.